# Read only the latest kafka messages

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

I am using this kind of configuration for the kakfa message consumption.

As soon as I am stopping the message on producer side it will go idle for few seconds and it will start reading old messages.

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, Boolean.TRUE);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer");

        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "100");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "100000");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "10000");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "500");
    props.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
```

I wanted to read only recent messages only.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below property to the `props`

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
```